# Error of Value of Type 'ViewController' has no member 'keyboardDidShow(notification:)' while converting project from swift 4 to swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

Error of Value of Type `ViewController` has no member `keyboardDidShow(notification:)` while converting project from **Swift 4** to **Swift 5**. Below is the code which is giving the error right now

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.keyboardDidShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: add keyboardDidShow() in your view controller.

Comment: Update question with error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the method implementation

```
class ViewController:UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.keyboardDidShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
   }
   @objc func keyboardDidShow(notification:NSNotification) {}
}
```

inside the vc